# pandas reading csv date as a string that's a 5 digit number

Tags: pandas, csv, datetime

I have a date in a .csv with format YYYY-MM-DD.  Pandas is reading it in as a string but instead of the format shown in the csv, it reads in as a 5 digit number, coded as a string.

I've tried:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['alert_date'], unit = 's')
pd.to_datetime(df['alert_date'], unit = 'D')
```

I've also tried calling out to read it as a string and let date parser take over. See below:

```
dtype_dict = {'alert_date':'str','lossdate1':'str', 'lossdate2':'str',
              'lossdate3':'str', 'lossdate4':'str', 'lossdate5':'str',
              'effdate':'str'}
parse_dates = ['lossdate1', 'lossdate2', 'lossdate3', 
               'lossdate4', 'lossdate5', 'effdate']
df  = pd.read_csv("Agent Alerts Earned and Incurred with Loss Dates as of Q3 2021.csv",
                  encoding='latin1', dtype = dtype_dict, parse_dates=parse_dates)
```

I'm not sure what else to try or what is wrong with it to begin with.

Here is an example of what the data looks like.

```
alertflag,alert_type,alert_date,effdate,cal_year,totalep,eufactor,product,NonCatincrd1,Catincrd1,lossdate1,NonCatcvrcnt1,Catcvrcnt1,NonCatincrd2,Catincrd2,lossdate2,NonCatcvrcnt2,Catcvrcnt2,NonCatincrd3,Catincrd3,lossdate3,NonCatcvrcnt3,Catcvrcnt3,NonCatincrd4,Catincrd4,lossdate4,NonCatcvrcnt4,Catcvrcnt4,NonCatincrd5,Catincrd5,lossdate5,NonCatcvrcnt5,Catcvrcnt5,incurred
1,CANCEL NOTICE,2019-06-06,2018-12-17,2019,91.00,0.96,444,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

The `alert_date` comes through on that record as 21706.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the content of the csv file?

Comment: Question edited with the addition of the data example

Comment: With your sample it works fine on my pc. Are you sure the date is in YYYY-MM-DD format in all rows?

Comment: I guess not all 300K rows.  i assumed since the head and tail were